# Irregular Next Autoindex after INSERT SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some tables that I'm trying to transfer data between.

When I execute the query to get the first 720 items from Table 1 and insert into Table 2, everthing works ok:

```
INSERT INTO `table_2` (`company_id`, `type_id`, `request`, `response`, `response_headers`, `datetime_added`, `timestamp_univ`)
SELECT `company_id`, `type_id`, `request`, `response`, `response_headers`, `datetime_added`, `timestamp_univ` 
FROM `table_1` 
WHERE id > '0' LIMIT 720;
```

However, the `Next Autoindex` value listed is 1024 instead of 721.

Any reason why this is happening?

**NOTE** I have two non-unique indexes on two columns of the table

Comment: What if you perform it with `LIMIT 1` ?

Comment: @zerkms The `LIMIT 720` is for the `SELECT`

Comment: I understand that. My question was: if you use `LIMIT 1` would the next autoincrement value be the expected or not?

Comment: As always, if you're depending in some way on the actual numeric values of automatically provided identifiers in your database, you're probably doing something wrong. Why does it *matter* to you that the next number it supplies will be 1024 rather than 721? There can be lots of reasons (e.g. rollbacks, explicit deletions) why the numbers will not be sequential, and avoiding gaps is expensive (which is why no database system offers such a generator by default, so far as I'm aware)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It matters because when next I insert something I would like the `id` to start from where it left off i.e. `721` and not `1024`. Is this an unreasonable expectation?! BTW, there are no other operations currently active on the database

Comment: As I said, there are lots of reasons why gaps *can* appear in such sequences. You should, ideally, treat them as opaque blobs that just happen to *fit* in numeric columns. If you're exposing them to your users such that they'll ask about gaps in the sequence, that's where I'd recommend focusing your effort - stop exposing these identifiers to your users. If you're not exposing them to your users, then as I originally said, what does it matter if (and *when*) gaps appear in the sequence. The gaps appear by the design.